# PHP магия с индексом массива

Tags: php

Всем добрый вечер, столкнулся с непонятной проблемой.
В скрипте:

```
var_dump(array_keys($obj->content->photo_self_thinking));
var_dump(array_key_exists("2", $obj->content->photo_self_thinking));
var_dump(array_key_exists(2, $obj->content->photo_self_thinking));
```

Выводит:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "3"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "4"
}
bool(false)bool(false)
```

Попытка обращения к соответствующему индексу заканчивается ошибкой E_NOTICE Undefined offset.
Что за магия?

Comment: Уверен, что проблема не совсем тут. Она скорее всего в том, что вы это делаете в цикле, где вы подставляете значение счётчика куда-либо и вот там уже на одной из итераций эту ошибку и выдает

Comment: текст нотиса целиком приведите, и убедитесь в том, что ошибка действительно  в этом файле и этой строке

Comment: И var_dump "массива" тоже не помешал бы. [Непонятно](https://3v4l.org/nsLVM), почему целочисленные ключи в array_keys имеют строковый тип.

Comment: @vp_arth ага, я почти успел удалить коммент )